Allow the user to view a deleted post if it has a pending flag
Currently, if you have a pending flag on a deleted post and you are <10k, you can't retract it anymore (at least not via UI), so it's basically stuck until someone reviews it.
This happens mainly with moderator intervention flags.
I suggest that users who have pending flags on deleted posts have the ability to view them, until the flag is resolved or retracted.
